# sfSmartsync().syncUp function giving success, but not reflected in changes on the Salesforce server

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

I am trying to implement syncUp function for offline devices in Salesforce on sendbox account with the following method:

```
var sfSmartsync = function() {
            return cordova.require("com.salesforce.plugin.smartsync");
        };
        target = {
        };

        /*target = {
         type : "Lead"
         query : "select * from {Lead}"
         };*/

        options = {
            mergeMode : sfSmartsync().MERGE_MODE.OVERWRITE,
            attributes: {type:"Lead"}
        };
        soupName = "Lead";
        // sfSmartsync().syncUp(false, target, soupName, options, function sucessCallback(params) {
        sfSmartsync().syncUp(soupName, options, function sucessCallback(params) {
            alert("Sync Up Sucess");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(params));

        }, function errorCallback() {
            alert("Sync Up Error");

        });
```

And I got a success which is :

```
{"status":"NEW","target":{"modificationDateFieldName":"LastModifiedDate","idFieldName":"Id","type":"rest"},"_soupEntryId":3,"maxTimeStamp":0,"totalSize":-1,"type":"syncUp","progress":0,"options":{"mergeMode":"OVERWRITE"},"soupName":"Lead"}
```

But when I go back to the Salesforce server I can't find my changes in the database. If anybody did something like that, then please help me.